# Using Android Youtube API to play Live streams

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am developing an Android app that uses the Android Youtube API.
I can successfully play any video from Youtube. However, when I try to play a live stream, I encounter some issues:

- When the latest version of Youtube is installed on my device (Youtube 11.13.56), I get the following message :
  "There was a problem while playing, Tap to retry"
- After removing youtube updates and going back to "youtube 10.18.55" version, everything works fine.

Any idea to handle this problem ?

Thanks for your help

Environment: Samsung Galaxy S4, Android 5.0.1, YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi-1.2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like YouTube fixed their SDK and live videos are now working again.

Comment: Will the exact code that works for normal youtube videos now work for live streaming video ID? Please confirm.

Answer (score 2):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21121259/how-can-i-play-youtube-live-streams-with-the-youtube-android-player-api), there is no difference in playing any videos from YouTube and playing a live stream. Latest version of YouTube app must also play live stream.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   

  YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
  youTubeView.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
}
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
        YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {

    player.loadVideo("UT86BH2LVUU"); //live vid

}
```

Make sure that you integrated `broadcasts` and `streams` properly based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/broadcasts-and-streams). The stream provides the content that will be broadcast to YouTube users. Once created, a `liveStream` resource can be bound to one or more [`liveBroadcast`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts) resources.

Here are [examples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/code_samples/java#create_a_broadcast) using YouTube Live Streaming API.

Comment: I am using the same source code, and I tried many video IDs:
 - When the ID is a live stream: it didn't work
 - When the ID is another video: it worked fine

Also, when I downgrade my Youtube app, it works fine for both (live and simple videos)

Maybe I am doing something wrong, but I really don't know exactly what.

Any help you can give will be greatly appreciated.