# How to play YouTube Live on ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'm trying to play YouTube Live with ExoPlayer on Android device.

I know that ExoPlayer can play YouTube, according to:
1. Karim Abdell Salam's answer:
[How to play youtube video in ExoPlayer in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607104/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-exoplayer-in-android)
2. Teyam's answer:
[Streaming a youtube live video to android app with exoplayer (DASH)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40761192/streaming-a-youtube-live-video-to-android-app-with-exoplayer-dash?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But, when I trying to post http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id=[video_id] I'm not getting **dashmpd** property at the response.
Also I tried https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id=[video_id]&el=info&ps=default&eurl=&gl=US&hl=en accoording to Karim Abdell Salam comment, and here I'm getting **status=fail&errorcode=2&reason=Invalid+parameters**.

So how should I play YouTube with ExoPlayer if I can't post **get_video_info** successfully?

Note:
I tried several YouTube videos, both Live and regular.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like YouTube has recently made some changes there, so try https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id=[video_id]&ps=default&eurl=&gl=US&hl=en i.e. without the el=info parameter which seems to not work anymore. This worked for me (especially for Live videos).
[This](https://www.tyrrrz.me/Blog/Reverse-engineering-YouTube) link will help you understand the significance of parameters like `el`. I am trying to solve a similar issue so if you find any other resources please do share.

Comment: So it's possible to play YouTube on ExoPlayer? Even without ads?

Comment: @SuryaPrakashKushawah i cheked your code it is not working. java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method ‘java.lang.String at.huber.youtubeExtractor.YtFile.getUrl()’